# Input stops working when I change value (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html-input

I just want to insert value in text input on https://hordes.io/clans website.

When you natively enter there characters, all elements load automatically. But when I do this:
`document.getElementsByClassName("navbtn")[0].value += "d"`
It neither loads new results nor works at all when you try to do anything manually afterwards.

In case with `document.getElementsByClassName("navbtn")[0].value += ""` it continues working.

I tried another method to enter values there: clicking input field - returns undefined.

Is there any way I can search on this page? By the way I did it just in chrome snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a decent solution. Their website makes a post request to their api --> https://hordes.io/api/claninfo/list.

You can pass json to specify which clan you want!
Like this:

POST: https://hordes.io/api/claninfo/list
PAYLOAD: {"name":"dmdw","order":1}

RESPONSE:

```
{"clans":[{"name":"Darkmetal Dwarfs","tag":"DmDw","level":9,"gold":"42141","faction":0,"members":"2","prestige":"9446"}]}
```

You can try the request on reqbin.com following this link with already filled in params: https://reqbin.com/oieogjuu

Generated code from reqbin.com:

```
var url = "https://hordes.io/api/claninfo/list";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }};

var data = '{"name":"dmdw","order":1}';

xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I never used anything like this before. This may be a way better and faster than scraping page!

Comment: I just need to learn how to make such requsests :)

Comment: When you want to automate something you just can check the requests the browsers makes under the network tab. Inside the requests you can see everything about the request like headers, payloads and so on... If you have any further questions feel free to ask me! (discord: STEPHEN HAWKING#2969)